# How do we determine the HTML element (eg DIV) from where a <script></script> tag is included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing an application where a user can upload a photo to my site and then embed this photo (along with certain extra information) any where else by including a script similar to this:

```
<script src="example.com/my.js"></script>
<script>MY.embed({id: "12345"})</script>
```

From within this embed script, I intend to create an `<img>` block and do other DOM manipulation to display the image. To achieve this, inside the `MY.embed()` function, I need to be able to know the `DIV` or `HTML` element (or maybe the previous or next HTML element) from where the function was called.

Is there a way to achieve this? jQuery is included inside `"example.com/my.js"` - so jQuery functionality is available.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by knowing the location?

Comment: @Ibu: I need to create an <img> tag and do other DOM manipulation to actually display the image in the same area that the user has placed the embed script. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: just print the content using document.write() its the easiest way

Comment: Try this: `$('script[src="example.com/my.js"]').parent()`

Comment: It's nice to avoid `document.write()` since it blocks the browser from rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this in stead?

```
<script src="example.com/my.js"></script>
<div class="MY-embed">{"id": "12345"}</div>
```

Use the my.js script to locate all divs with class `MY-embed` and parse the innerHTML as JSON. Use the result to replace the content of the div with an image element and do your manipulations.

a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2cErA/2/) (Chrome, firefox)

**Note**

You could also create a [HTML5 version](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) as follows:

```
<div class="MY-embed" data-id="12345"></div>
```

And use the `dataset` attribute of the div element to retrieve the id.

Comment: This looks like the best option of the lot. Especially the HTML5 version. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Most javascripits like this are using [document.write()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp). With that, your scripts writes to the position where it was included.

And after you placed a div somewhere, you may find it in the DOM by it's id.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var index = 0; index < scripts.length; index++) {
    var script = scripts[index];
    if (script.src.indexOf("my.js") != -1) {
        //found the script, do what you want with the parent node here
        alert(script.parentNode.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, but I haven't tested, that since javascript is run as the document is parsed, whatever the last script tag in the dom is, is the script tag you're inside.